# How to let a Reference Field accept multiple Document schemas in MongoEngine?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

Context: I am writing an API (using Flask and MongoEngine) with multiple account types, including perhaps buildings. I need the database to hold some temporary accounts until a particular building registers.

This is how I've been referencing just one type of user:

```
current_holder_of_stuff = ReferenceField(ActiveUser)
```

I know GenericReferenceField is also an option, but what if I only want to allow two types of references? Is there anything like:

```
current_holder_of_stuff = ReferenceField(ActiveUser, TempUser)
```

Muchos thankos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may work to create a parent class of type `User` and then [have inherited classes](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance) of `ActiveUser` and `TempUser` to deal with the various user types. As for the requirement for `current_holder_of_stuff` to be two possible document types, you cannot use a single reference field. As you've dismissed using `GenericReferenceField` then one way might be to add a property method and a `StringField` with options such as this:

```
import mongoegine as mdb

class User(mdb.Document):
    name = mdb.StringField()

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class ActiveUser(User):
    activation_date = mdb.DateTimeField()

class TempUser(User):
    date_limit = mdb.DateTimeField()

class Building(mdb.Document):
    address = mdb.StringField()

class Stuff(mdb.Document):
    user = mdb.ReferenceField(User)
    building = mdb.ReferenceField(Building)
    currently_with = mdb.StringField(options=['user','building'],required=True)

    @property
    def current_holder_of_stuff(self):
        if self.currently_with == "user":
            return self.user
        else:
            return self.building
```

You can also use mongoengine's [signals](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/signals.html) to perform checks pre-save to ensure there is only a user or building defined.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution to the specific. What if I wanted the ReferenceField to hold either a User or a Building though?

Comment: A `ReferenceField` must hold a single document type. If you need to allow multiple options then I would use `GenericReferenceField` and then use [signals](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/signals.html) to perform a check that it is a `User`or `Building`. This seems a bit inelegant to me though , I've edited my answer to give a slightly better solution (I'm sure there is an even better one out there)

Comment: @SteveRossiter Can you please elaborate more on how to use signals to check the field type?